# Sonarqube could not connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, database-connection, sonarqube

I'm trying to connect Sonarqube to PostgreSQL but it throws the following error at start.

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.05.06 17:47:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/ssd/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search*/ org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process1977113005492303949properties
2015.05.06 17:47:45 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.05.06 17:47:45 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.05.06 17:47:46 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] version[1.4.4], pid[13920], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.05.06 17:47:46 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] initializing ...
2015.05.06 17:47:46 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1430945265510] loaded [], sites []
2015.05.06 17:47:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] initialized
2015.05.06 17:47:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] starting ...
2015.05.06 17:47:47 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1430945265510] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.30:9001]}
2015.05.06 17:47:47 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1430945265510] sonarqube/jY5aYsfmTVW5G1BE521uBg
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1430945265510] new_master [sonar-1430945265510][jY5aYsfmTVW5G1BE521uBg][OobjTestServer][inet[/192.168.0.30:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1430945265510}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] started
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1430945265510] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/ssd/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server*/:/ssd/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process3509085435217188319properties
2015.05.06 17:47:50 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.05.06 17:47:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /ssd/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web
2015.05.06 17:47:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.05.06 17:47:51 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015.05.06 17:47:51 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1430945265510] loaded [], sites []
2015.05.06 17:47:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1 / 4aa9af3a6a4362b61db365fba32eb0a55d411e7a
2015.05.06 17:47:52 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
2015.05.06 17:47:52 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:117) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:73) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:96) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_76]
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Conexão negada. Verifique se o nome da máquina e a porta estão corretos e se o postmaster está aceitando conexões TCP/IP.)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:115) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Conexão negada. Verifique se o nome da máquina e a porta estão corretos e se o postmaster está aceitando conexões TCP/IP.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:144) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexão recusada
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
2015.05.06 17:47:52 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_76-b13 [linux-amd64]
2015.05.06 17:47:52 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.05.06 17:47:56 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_76]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.get(JRubyFacade.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getDatabase(JRubyFacade.java:209) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$1.create(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$RackApplicationImpl.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:420) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:111) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.doInit(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:94) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
2015.05.06 17:47:56 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Error listenerStart
2015.05.06 17:47:56 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2015.05.06 17:47:56 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2015.05.06 17:47:56 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015.05.06 17:47:56 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015.05.06 17:47:56 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.05.06 17:47:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.05.06 17:47:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2015.05.06 17:47:56 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isReady(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isReady(WebServer.java:45) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:80) ~[sonar-process-5.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:66) [sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
2015.05.06 17:47:56 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] stopping ...
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] stopped
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] closing ...
2015.05.06 17:47:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1430945265510] closed
2015.05.06 17:47:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
```

So I checked the user credentials (properties prefixed with **sonar.jdbc**) and it's all Ok. The user *sonarqube* is created into Database. Can someone help?

Here's the **sonar.properties** file:

```
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters.
# See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Settings+Encryption

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=sonarqube

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# It does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# server and the analyzers must be executed on the same host.
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube

# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092

#----- MySQL 5.x
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance

#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.* of Oracle JDBC driver are supported, even if connecting to lower Oracle versions.
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2005/2008
# Only the distributed jTDS driver is supported.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

#----- Connection pool settings
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default its heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options. Enabling the HotSpot Server VM
# mode (-server) is recommended.
# Note that the option -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 is mandatory.
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings
# like -Djava.awt.headless=true
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
#sonar.web.port=9000

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file.
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# Access logs are generated in the file logs/access.log. This file is rolled over when it's 5Mb.
# An archive of 3 files is kept in the same directory.
# Access logs are enabled by default.
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1

# OTHER CONFIGURATIONS ABOUT INTERNAL FEATURES... (LDAP, SEARCH, ETC...)
# We can comment everything after this line...
```

Comment: Are you sure correct database is un-commented  inside sonar/conf/sonar.properties file ?

Comment: Please post the relevant entries from your ``sonar.properties``, especially the ``sonar.jdbc.xxx`` properties. You might also want to double check your TCP ports settings and eventually firewall settings.

Comment: The `sonar.properties` file's posted.

Comment: The pb does not seem to come from SonarQube configuration. You should check that jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube is accessible from the machine with the given user.

Comment: We can close this question. Re-install everything solved the pb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Years after this, someone upvoted my question.

So, I came here to read the question, and as I still working with this, I made a new installation of my whole system in 2015. And all the things worked well. At the time I didn't realized that the problem is just the missing port in Postgres configuration.

Now, reading the question again and looking to my server configuration, I've find out that replacing this line should solve the problem:

`sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube`

to

`sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonarqube`

Comment: Let me confirm that this fixes the error, just make sure that SonarQube.bat is stopped before you do the changes, the started once you have them. Works on 7.7

Comment: Thanks @OmarAyala but I was using version 4.5.6